# Using new RegExp and getting a return of /(?:)/?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, express

I am trying to combine three regex and can't seem to get it to work correctly.
I want to be able to have these three be combined and if possible ignore case. 
This is what I have so far:

```
const params = {};
    let btc = '';
    let sys = '';
    let zec = '';

    console.log(typeof req.query);
    req.query.btc == 'true'
      ? (btc = /BTC/i && (params.paymentoptions_display = new RegExp(btc + sys + zec)))
      : { ...params };
    req.query.sys == 'true'
      ? (sys = /SYS/i && (params.paymentoptions_display = new RegExp(btc + sys + zec)))
      : { ...params };
    req.query.zec == 'true'
      ? (zec = /ZEC/i && (params.paymentoptions_display = new RegExp(btc + sys + zec)))
      : { ...params };

    console.log(params);
```

I have not messed with these to much so I am not really sure at all where I am going wrong. I just want to be able to set my object `paymentoptions_display` value to a combination of these depending if the req.query.value is true.

If all three conditions are true then this is what I am getting in the return:

`{ paymentoptions_display: /\/(?:)\/\/\/(?:)\/\// }`

Comment: Is your req.query.value returning the string value 'true' or the boolean true? if the latter then that may be an issue. true != 'true'.

Comment: that is not the case I added an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant concatenate regular expressions like that, they are not strings.

That being said, I wholeheartedly recommend writing less "clever" code.

```
const params = {}, symbols = [];

if (req.query.btc == 'true') symbols.push("BTC"); else { ...params };
if (req.query.sys == 'true') symbols.push("SYS"); else { ...params };
if (req.query.zec == 'true') symbols.push("ZEC"); else { ...params };

params.paymentoptions_display = new RegExp(symbols.join('|'), "i");

console.log(params);
```

Comment: On the `...params` I think you need to add a {} around it,but this worked! Thank you very much! I have never used these and just did research and others said you could combine them using that.

Comment: I wasn't sure what `{ ...params }` was supposed to mean, I assumed it was a placeholder for something.

Comment: @TaylorAustin Regarding your edit suggestion: I did not use ternary operators here for a reason. They are the wrong tool in this situation.

Comment: The ternary operator is an expression. It's for calculating a result value, not for flow control. Using it for flow control makes code harder to read. Hard to read code is prone to bugs and unexpected behavior. In short, it's bad style.